# How do I make it so a while loop terminates immediately when the condition is false?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to make a while loop terminate right when it's false without:

```
while condition:
    if !condition:
        break
    ...
    if !condition:
        break
    ...
    if !condition:
        break
    ...
```

eg

```
while led_blink:
    if !led_blink:
        break
    led.value(1)
    if !led_blink:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    if !led_blink:
        break
    led.value(0)
    if !led_blink:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

If it helps, I'm using MicroPython for the Raspberry PI pico W

You know what, I'm just gonna join a programming discord

Comment: Simply check every time condition may become false

Comment: @user16217248 But that's annoying, I'm asking is there a way to _not_ have to do that

Comment: Show us a minimal reproducible example of the condition and the conditionally run code.

Comment: @KlausD. I was making an led blink code that I wanted to terminate really quick, ill put it in the post

Comment: Why do you recheck `led_blink` after just sleeping? Sleeping doesn't change its value.

Answer (score -2):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to know for sure, but this may be helpful.

```
conditions = [True, False, True]

while all(conditions):
  print("To infinity and beyond")
  break
```

Running that you'll notice nothing happens, because there is a `False` in `conditions`.

Changing it to `True` and you'll see `To infinity and beyond` printed in your terminal. Note: I added the break there just to avoid an infinite loop.

Documentation for `all()`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp